# Laravel form generate bad html

Tags: php, html, code-generation, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have a problem that can seems easy but when i generate html with my blade i have strange effect. I generate my form like this:

`<form name="form" action="/page" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
</form>`

And Laravel generate a code like this:

`<form name="form" action="/page" method="post"></form>
@csrf
<input type="checkbox" name="check">`

I just don't understand why this do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: change your input element as <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>.

Comment: The problem isn't resolved